# how to import com.gene.herder.google.GoogleApiSettings;?

Tags: java

I want to find the **`.jar to import this library`**

```
import com.gene.herder.google.GoogleApiSettings;
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this:

```
 <!-- Google API -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev22-1.13.2-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
```